# How to change the color of active tab in ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

I am trying to change the color of the selected tab in ionic 4, but I have faced some challenges. I am using the tabs template. I tried editing it in `chrome://inspect` and it worked but when I built for android it takes no effect.

What do I need to change?

Comment: You need to change the `.scss` file as you have changed in `chrome://inspect`.
and run the project.

Comment: i tried that but i does not take effect, i tried this: .tab-btn-selected, .tab-btn:hover {
    color: red;
}

Comment: did you refer this https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-tabs-change-active-tab-border-icon-color/100110/11

Comment: @yushin would you be so kind as to explain how you managed to solve this specific issue in the end? I can't seem to get it working even though I worked with the variables in many other places inside our V4 apps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jparg i managed to get this done by going to this https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/theming/color-generator i generated what i want my theme to be like the copied the results under CSS Variables into the file under theme folder called variables.scss.

Comment: Thx @yushin. I had tried that already. It seems to me that my current situation is more bug related, though. Appreciate you taking the time to answer.

Comment: what does the bug say in the log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought Ionic 4 was all shadow DOM. I may be wrong, but according to what I've been reading, you  have to use CSS variables to get at the shadow-dom styles in Ionic 4. See, for example: https://www.joshmorony.com/a-primer-on-css-4-variables-for-ionic-4/

Comment: You right i managed to figure it out yesterday, though i had a few challenges creating a custom theme as it required an already existing theme to be applied. so i modified one of the the themes and managed to get it to the theme i required it to be at.

Answer (score 4):

Just use ion-tab-button CSS custom properties, `--color-selected`   Color of the selected tab button:

```
 ion-tab-button {
  --color-selected: red;
 }
```

Ref: [ion-tab-button](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tab-button)